# Issue with downloading files from gDrive with Google API for .NET

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an application since several years with which users can load data from gDrive. The data can be from native Google spreadsheets (gSheets) or files like txt, csv, xlsx. Suddenly since sometimes this week however files cannot be downloaded anymore, although nothing changed on our side. When I try to download a file, I get now the content of an html page that is basically a login screen. However the **content of gSheets can still be downloaded**, so it cannot be due to some access issues of the service account I'm using. I also can confirm that the files are still shared with that service account.
I'm using this code to download the files:

```
        String serviceAccountEmail = this.apiConfig.ClientIdEmail;
        Byte[] keyFile = this.apiConfig.FileP12;

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive Spotfire Datasource",
        });

        var response = service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(exportUrl).Result;
        Stream downloadStream = new MemoryStream(response);
```

The "exportUrl" has the format

```
https://docs.google.com/a/<domain.com>/uc?id=<fileId>&export=download&gid=0
```

and when I try this Url in the browser I can download the file without a problem. 
I tried in the meantime with the latest dlls from NuGet (version 1.38) for both Google.Apis.Drive.v2 and Google.Apis.Drive.v3.
Does anyone have an idea why these downloads are not working anymore all of a sudden?

Comment: It looks like you are using the service-account authenticated http client to then do a direct download. I know you state that the service account still has file access permissions, but the most likely cause of the issue is that the permissions on the files has changed, and the service account is no longer authorized to access the files. This would explain why you're seeing an authorization html page instead of the expected file content. Your `exportURL` may work in the browser as you are already logged-in in the browser.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your comment. I checked in gDrive that the files are still shared with the service account. And they do, just like the gSheets are still shared with it. In fact I also created a new service account with a new p12 file, shared the file in gDrive with this new account and the same issue still happens.

Comment: Just tried with Google.Apis.Drive.v3. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution. It turns out that another URL needs to be used when downloading files:

```
    String serviceAccountEmail = this.apiConfig.ClientIdEmail;
    Byte[] keyFile = this.apiConfig.FileP12;

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }
       }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Drive Spotfire Datasource",
    });

    //get file handler
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get(this.uniqueKey).Execute();
    if (!file.MimeType.Equals("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"))
    {
        //for files use another Url
        exportUrl = file.DownloadUrl;
    }
    var response = service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(exportUrl).Result;
    Stream downloadStream = new MemoryStream(response);
```